# Http Get request unauthorized

Tags: android, http, authentication, http-headers

I'm having issues with authorization to url :
 " https://staging.snapsmedia.io/api/assets/findByTags?tagNames=beaumoji ".The key is ‘Authorization’ and the value is ‘Basic NTdlZWI4NWJjOTdhY2E1NDZlNmM5ZjNiOjYwZWY0MjdlODc0MTExZTY5MjM0MDEyMzQ1Njc4OWFi’ . I tried to put authorization before and after "assets", tried in the end of address. Still nothing works: it always returns me "unauthorized".  Run out of ideas how I can make it work. I would highly appreciate all suggestions!
Thank you!

Comment: Please can u post what you have tried? I mean the code

Comment: Hi! I've tried dozens upon dozens of combinations. Here are some of the attempts...   'https://makesnaps.com/api/assets/findbytags?tagNames=beaumoji?Authorization=BasicNTdlZWI4NWJjOTdhY2E1NDZlNmM5ZjNiOjYwZWY0MjdlODc0MTExZTY5MjM0MDEyMzQ1Njc4OWFi'     'https://makesnaps.com/api/assets/findbytags?Authorization=BasicNTdlZWI4NWJjOTdhY2E1NDZlNmM5ZjNiOjYwZWY0MjdlODc0MTExZTY5MjM0MDEyMzQ1Njc4OWFi' as well as, 'https://makesnaps.com/api/Authorization=BasicNTdlZWI4NWJjOTdhY2E1NDZlNmM5ZjNiOjYwZWY0MjdlODc0MTExZTY5MjM0MDEyMzQ1Njc4OWFi/assets/findbytags?tagNames=beaumoji'  I've also been trying with Postman